# Create one template html for different urls

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, backend

I have a shopping website where the user can go from all products page to a particular product page.

Currently I have the following strcuture:

1. User is in the following url:

[www.example.com/furniture/tables.html](http://www.example.com/furniture/tables.html)

In the above url the user can see all the tables.

2. From the above url, the user can click on any of the tables (let's say the table has a name "xyz") and he is taken to the following url:

[www.example.com/furniture/tables/product.html](http://www.example.com/furniture/tables/product.html)

product.html is my template html which I fill up with info relevant to the table "xyz" by fetching the info from database.

Now, what I want to achieve is to have a url with the product name itself and not a general template name. In this case, I want to have:

[www.example.com/furniture/tables/xyz.html](http://www.example.com/furniture/tables/xyz.html)

instead of

[www.example.com/furniture/tables/product.html](http://www.example.com/furniture/tables/product.html)

The primary use case of this is that I want to add a particular product's url to some other websites, where the users can click on the link and be taken to that specific product's page which is contained in a general template file after all.

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. Some libraries exist solely for this issue. AFAIK, this is called route parameters in express. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, all I am using for the website is javascript/jquery and firebase for backend. No other libraries or frameworks are involved. Is there another way without any extra tools?

Comment: Definitely, how are you currently handling routing? How do you render pages based on the url?

Comment: You can use django or flask templating language

Comment: @evolutionxbox in my example in question, when the user clicks on xyz table the url "www.example.com/furniture/tables/product.html" is triggered. This url is triggered by clicking on any of the products in fact. It's same url for all products. It's just I grab the name of the products, xyz in this example and with that name I go to DB and retrieve whatever info I need for the product page.

Comment: So you’re currently using static html files and the db fetching is done client-side? Do you expect “xyz.html” to be dynamic?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, I just query the db with js and then fill the html with fetched info

Comment: Currently it’s not possible as the html name is decided by you when you make the html file. Some kind of html renderer needs to be used to allow dynamic html rendering. Common technologies for this include node/express, php, ruby, etc

Comment: ok, I see and how would I do it dynamic without involving express and stuff like that?

Comment: without some form of backend server/technology? Probably could use query parameters? `example.com/product.html?id=uniqueID`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update the displayed URL (without reloading the page), you can use [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

```
window.history.pushState('', '', 'http://www.example.com/furniture/tables/'+product_name+'.html');
```

Comment: This is useful, but if a user loads that URL directly it will fail.

Comment: Exactly, I don't see any other way doing this unless using query parameters since he doesn't want to involve other stuff.

Comment: yes, that's exactly it, a direct url will be used. I'll try with the query parameters. Thanks for all responses